# react axios returning data with useEffect "Cannot read property 'numero' of undefined"

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I would like to fetch one mock api using axios, but it is getting an error.

1. Variable with the useEffect to fetch the api

```
     const AnaliseDocumentacao = () => {
           const [solicitacao, setSolicitacao] = useState();
           useEffect(() => {
             axios
               .get('http://localhost:3333/solicitacao')
               .then(res => {
                 console.log('res: ', res);
                 setSolicitacao(res.data)
               })
               .catch(err => {
                 console.error(err);
               })
           }, [])
```

2. Mock data

```
    {
      "solicitacao": {
        "numero": "9999.999.999999999",
        "linhaCredito": "XXXXX Loren Ipsun ###",
        "valor": "R$999.999,00",
        "prazo": "99 dias",
        "empresa": {
          "cnpj": "00.000.000/0001-00",
          "razaoSocial": "Loren ipsum Ltda"
        },
        "responsavel": {
          "abc": "aaaa",
          "telefone": "(00)0000-0000"
        }
      }
    }
```

3. Try to get the field "numero", but it's getting an error:

```
    console.log('solicitacao: ', solicitacao.numero)
```

"Cannot read property 'numero' of undefined"

Comment: Can you provide the output of console.log('res: ', res); ?

Answer (score 2):

Your useEffect callback function will set the state of solicitacao as

```
    {
     "solicitacao": {
         "numero": "9999.999.999999999",
         .....
      }
    }
```

Either you need to use **setSolicitacao(res.data['solicitacao'])** to access **solicitacao.numero** or with your current code, try accessing **solicitacao.solicitacao.numero**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with the code you've provided. It is likely to a be an issue with the api you have set up locally. Try switching out `'localhost:3333'` with `'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'`. Taken from [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

If something is logged to the console then the issue definitely with your API implementation rather than your front end code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answer, after some tests I find that the variable at the useState was wrong.
I changed:

```
const [solicitacao, setSolicitacao] = useState();
```

to this, instead and it works:

```
const [solicitacao, setSolicitacao] = useState([]);
```

I just included the "[]" at the useState.